# Use local lerna packages as scripts on the root folder

Tags: npm, lerna, monorepo

I have several packages inside `scripts` that used in root.

I use `npm link scripts/babel-preset` which enables me to use the `preset` in the main `babel.config.js` and I wonder if this is the right way to do it or I miss the obvious here?

```
root
|-- packages/
|-- scripts
    |-- babel-preset
|-- babel.config.js
|-- package.json
|-- lerna.json
```

I am aware of `lerna bootstrap` but it works in sub-folders between siblings.
My issue is using packages in root.

**Is there anyway to use scripts in the root without using `npm link` for every single package?**

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

In root `package.json` I added required scripts as local `devDependencies`:

```
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        ....
        "babel-preset": "file:scripts/babel-preset",
        ....
    }
}
```

It works fine with `npm install`

**UPDATE**:

If you are using `yarn` you don't need any internal link. `Yarn` will take care of everything.